# How can I fix GVim Window size?

Tags: 12.10, gvim, vim-plugin

This might not be a bug, but I've installed the Vim plugin package, [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim).

My GVim window looks like this screenshot, which seems too big:

[image]

This might not be an issue with spf13-vim, since I've used it on Windows without problems. Can anyone point me in the right direction so that I can see, say, 40 lines on the window at once?

My current font within Vim is Sans size 10.

Comment: Could someone re-post the image to imgur using StackExchange's uploader? The image is blocked where I am ATM.

Comment: Are you sure that is a size 10 font? It looks much larger. Place the following line in your `~/.gvimrc` file: `set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 10`

Comment: Bert, you are right. The problem seems to be with the Sans font that appears so large even with the size of 10. I've switched to Ubuntu Mono with size 13 now and it works great.

Answer (score 6):

In my .gvimrc file I have:

```
set lines=64
set columns=90
```

to set the initial window size.

This is for gvim, the GUI vim.

In the console, vim spans the terminal dimensions.

You can also enter the `:scriptnames` command. It will show the list of the files sourced by vim at startup.
One of those files might be setting the window size you don't like. Check from last to first, because the settings might be in more than one file.